# elFinder Open Different Folders

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, elfinder

I'm developing a small webapp on which I'm using elFinder, so users can browse some remote dirs.

The main problem I'm having is that I can open the root of the remote folder, but the objective is to have dedicated links directly to each folder.

Right now I'm using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myCommands = elFinder.prototype._options.commands;
  var disabled = ['extract', 'archive','home','quicklook','rm','duplicate','rename','mkdir','mkfile','copy','cut','paste','edit','archive','search','resize'];
  $.each(disabled, function(i, cmd) {
    (idx = $.inArray(cmd, myCommands)) !== -1 && myCommands.splice(idx,1);
  });
  var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
    url : 'elfinder/php/connector.php', // connector URL (REQUIRED)
    width: 1024,
    height: 768, 
    commands: myCommands, 
  }).elfinder('instance');
});
```

And my html is something like this:

```
<div id="modal_reuniaoproducao" class="modal container fade" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Responsive</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div id="elfinder"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Would it be possible with the same connector to change the folder I want to open on each modal?

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use the events system like is said in Bootstrap's documentation. 
For exemple, register the show event for each modal.

```
$('#modal_reuniaoproducao').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    // do something, in this case open elfinder.
    var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
                 url : 'elfinder/php/connector.php', // connector URL (REQUIRED)
                 width: 1024,
                 height: 768, 
                 commands: myCommands, 
               }).elfinder('instance');
});
```

And you can send the "control" with method get to connector.php, like connector.php&folderState=1. Its just an example.

Don't forget to destroy clean modal body on close and clear elfinder instance so when you make another call to connector you have a "clean sheet".

I Hope it helps.

Comment: I forgot to mention the Boostrap's page link. Here it is http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals